# C++//STL to OBJ Converter: How can i make my program run faster

Tags: c++, 3d, converters, stl-format, format-conversion

I am creating an "STL to OBJ" format converter. The program contains a header file that reads the data from an STL file. and the main program takes that data and writes it to a new OBJ file.
everything works great but with large files the program takes so long. I know exactly which part makes the program slow and I can't find any alternative of it. It is in the part "// Create Array for the Faces" exactly  in the For-Loop.

First I want to explain a bit about STL and OBJ files. In general, any 3D image in the STL format is created from a large number of triangles and each triangle has 3 vertices (each vertex has 3 points: x, y and z). But there are many repeated vertices because the triangles are connected to each other. But in the OBJ format, 2 parts are responsible for it: one is "List of Vertices" and here vertices are sorted one after another without repetition. the second part is "List of Faces" and it is the Numbers of Index of the vertices.

this is my main code:

```
#include "Header.h"
using namespace std;
string inputFile = "Fidgit.stl";    //Import einen STL-Datei (1.6MB)

string outputFile = "Fidgit1.obj";  //Export einen OBJ-Datei (1.1MB)

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{


    auto t0 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Lesen der STL-Datei" << std::endl;

    std::vector<float> coords, normals;
    std::vector<unsigned int> tris, solids;
    stl_reader::ReadStlFile(inputFile.c_str(), coords, normals, tris, solids);
    const size_t numTris = tris.size() / 3;
    std::cout << "  Numbers of Triangels: " << numTris << std::endl;
    auto t1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t1 - t0);
    std::cout << "  duration: " << elapsed.count() << " ms" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "writing OBJ-File" << std::endl;

    std::ofstream fileOBJ(outputFile.c_str(), std::ios::out);

    std::cout << "  Erstelle Liste der Punkte" << std::endl;

    fileOBJ << "# Object name:" << std::endl;
    fileOBJ << outputFile << std::endl;
    fileOBJ << std::endl;
    fileOBJ << "# Begin list of vertices" << std::endl;
    vector<string> AllVertex;
    std::ifstream inFile(outputFile.c_str(), std::ios::in);
   ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   // Find Vertiecs coordinates and write into OBJ file

    for (size_t itri = 0; itri < numTris; ++itri) {
        for (size_t icorner = 0; icorner < 3; ++icorner) {
            float* c = &coords[3 * tris[3 * itri + icorner]];
            std::string VerStr = "v " + to_string(c[2]) + " " + to_string(c[1]) + " " + to_string(c[0]) ;
            AllVertex.push_back(VerStr);
        }
    }

    // here is a vertices containing the vertices coordinates read from the STL file.
    // But there are many repeated vectors that we don't need in obj format,
    // so they have to be removed by next step
    vector <string> OldSTLVertex = AllVertex;

    //Copy of STL vectors before removing the repeated vertices
    // to be able to find the faces indexes
    sort(AllteVertex.begin(), AllVertex.end());
    auto last = unique(AllVertex.begin(), AllVertex.end());
    AllVertex.erase(last, AllVertex.end());
    vector <string> OBJVertex = AllVertex;
    // here are the vectors without repetitions
    // ready to be able to save the vector coordinates in the created obj file:
    for (auto ind : OBJVertex)
    {
        fileOBJ << ind << endl;
    }
    fileOBJ << "# End list of vertices" << std::endl;
    fileOBJ << std::endl;

    auto t2 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1);
    std::cout << "    duration: " << elapsed.count() << " ms" << std::endl;
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Create Arry for the Faces
    std::cout << "  Create list of faces (triangles)" << std::endl;
    vector <int> OBJFaces(numTris * 3);
    fileOBJ << "# Begin list of faces" << std::endl;

    int iCounter = 0;
    int iPercent = 0;
    int vcounter = 0;

    // the point here is: which index in OBJVertiecs[] hat jeder vertiec in OldSTLVertex[]
    for (int i = 0; i < OldSTLVertex.size(); i++)   // in my example OldSTLVertex.size() have 99030 elements
    {
        bool bFound = false;
        int vertexIndex = 0;
        while (!bFound) // for (size_t vertexIndex = 0; vertexIndex < OBJVertex.size(); ++vertexIndex)
        {
            if (OldSTLVertex[i] == OBJVertex[vertexIndex])   // OBJVertex have 16523 elements
            {
                bFound = true;
                OBJFaces[vcounter] = vertexIndex;
                vcounter++;
            }
            vertexIndex++;
        }
        iCounter++;
        if (iCounter % (OldSTLVertex.size() / 100) == 0)    // every time 10% are done
        {
            iPercent = iPercent + 1;
            auto t3 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
            elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t3 - t2);
            std::cout << "    " << iPercent << "% done in " << elapsed.count() << " ms" << std::endl;
        }
    }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Write faces into OBJ file
    unsigned count = 0;
    for (auto ind : OBJFaces)
    {
        if (count++ % 3 == 0) fileOBJ << "f ";
        fileOBJ << ind + 1 << " ";
        if (count % 3 == 0) fileOBJ << std::endl;
    }
    fileOBJ << "# End list of faces" << std::endl;
    fileOBJ << std::endl;

    auto t4 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t4 - t0);
    std::cout << "OBJ file written in " << elapsed.count() << " ms." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *but with large files the program takes so long* -- Any question regarding the speed of a C++ program must be accompanied by 1) The compiler used, 2) Compiler version used, and 3) Optimization settings used when building the program.  If you're timing a "debug" or unoptimized build, then whatever you are stating as far as the speed of the program, is basically meaningless.

Comment: In addition, timing file writing highly depends on the hardware itself.  A slow disk means slower speed.

Comment: I've only had a very brief look, but I noticed you are looping through a vector of strings to find a match (OBJVertex[vertexIndex]).  Perhaps if you stored the data in a std::map using the string as the key you might get an improvment.

Comment: As @PaulMcKenzie says writing to a file can be slow.  It might be better to create the file in memory and then write it to disk in a single hit or at least chunks of 4KB or greater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code first maps all vertices in the STL to the OBJ string format of the vertex index they reference, then uses `std::unique` to reduce this list, then uses an O(n) lookup on each vertex to find the original index. This is O(n*m) and is very expensive if both n and m are large.

Instead, you can do the following:

1. Walk the elements of `tris`, and for each referenced vertex `idx` use a `std::map<std::tuple<float, float, float>, unsigned int>` to deduplicate them.

   1. If it is not present, you push the coord triple to a vector `obj_coords` and overwrite `tris[idx]` with its new index.
   2. If it was present you simply overwrite `tris[idx]` with the existing index.
2. When rendering the vectors you can almost dump `obj_coords` as-is.
3. When rendering the faces, you simply follow the indirection in `coords`

So, in summary:

```
using Coord = std::tuple<float, float, float>;

std::map<Coord, int> coordToIndex;
std::vector<Coord> obj_coords;

for (auto &idx : tris) {
  const Coord c = { coords[3*idx+0], coords[3*idx+1], coords[3*idx+2] };
  if (auto it = coordToIndex.find(c); it != coordToIndex.end()) {
    // We saw this vertex before
    idx = it->second;
  } else {
    // New vertex.
    obj_coords.push_back(c);
    idx = obj_coords.size()-1;
    coordToIndex[c] = idx; // Also create an entry in coordToIndex
  }
}
```

Then, generating vertexes is simple: (not sure why you swapped z and x though)

```
for (const auto& coord : obj_coords) {
    fileOBJ << "v " << std::get<2>(coord) << " " << std::get<1>(coord) << " " << std::get<0>(coord) << "\n";
}
```

And finally, the faces:

```
for (int tri = 0; tri < tris.size(); tri += 3) {
  fileOBJ << "f " << tris[tri+0] << " " << tris[tri+1] << " " << tris[tri+2] << "\n"
}
```

You may have noticed I use `"\n"` instead of `std::endl`. This is because `std::endl` implies `std::flush`, which tries to ensure that data is written to disk. Calling this is as often as you will is wasteful.
Instead, you can just flush once manually, or trust that the destructor will do it for you:

```
fileOBJ << std::flush;
```

Comment: I think you really did a great job and that what i really wanted.
I tried that but I got errors, maybe I didn't put something in the right place. I uploaded the files (2 headers, 1 cpp and one example) in this link. can you please take a look and see where are the mistakes? maybe you can write the full .cpp text
https://easyupload.io/uzd20s

i will be really grateful, I am now totally new to my first internship for college and I have been getting a headache from this program

Comment: Please keep communication on the platform. I just spotted and fixed one mistake.

Comment: okey then. two errors in "if(auto it = coordToIndex.find(c); it != coordToIndex.end())" the first one in "it": expression must have bool type (or be convertible to bool)
the second one with ";" : expected a ')'
and the last one in "idx = it->snd;"  :   class "std::pair<const std::tuple<float, float, float>, int>" has no member "snd"

Comment: yes, the `if(EXPR; COND)` form is a C++17 feature. If you are not compiling as C++17 you need to pull that apart in `auto it = ...; if (it != coordToIndex.end()) { ... }` Or just turn on C++17 support.

Comment: And the snd thing is another stupid typo. Should be second.

Comment: you are my Hero man! i fixed the mistakes and now the program works perfectly. now the duration 5 seconds instead of 120 seconds before and what I wanted. really really thank you.